# What WooCommerce hook should I use to make sure my content will always be displayed even in widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a product label plugin which looks like this on the shop page

[image]

I'm using the `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` hook for the shop page and `woocommerce_product_thumbnails` for the product page to add this label over the image. The problem is that the label isn't displayed in woocommerce widget blocks. Is there a different hook for displaying content in woocommerce blocks or I'm doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The hooks are woocommerce_widget_product_item_start and woocommerce_widget_product_item_end that you can use.  https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-content-widget-product.html

Comment: Im with latest woocommerce version, are you sure these hooks are not outdated? Because nothing is being displayed. Im testing it with `add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_start', function() {
    echo "test";
} );`

Comment: blocks and widgets are different things. So for blocks cant help since i avoid them at all cost :D

Comment: Im new at plugin development tbh. Does blocks have hooks which I can use?